# Only Draw background where Children Views are not?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to prevent over-draw in my app, and in one of the root views I'd like to detect the location of my children views, and then draw a background for where they are not. From my understanding, clipping would clip outside of the path, but what I'd really like to do is not draw at certain locations on the screen where the children are. Is there a good way to do this?

**EDIT**:
So I haven't played with canvas in a while, but I'm looking to do something like this:

```
public class ContainerView extends FrameLayout {

    private final Paint mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
    private final Path mPath = new Path();

    public ContainerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_background));
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawPaint(mBackgroundPaint);

        mPath.reset();
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            mPath.addRect(child.getLeft(), child.getTop(), child.getRight(), child.getBottom(),
                    Path.Direction.CCW); // What direction do I want?
        }

        canvas.clipPath(mPath);
    }
}
```

clipPath just wont do what I want though, I don't think. I think that would clip outside the path, and I need to clip inside the path.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to do something like override `onLayout` and at the end of it:

- iterate over all your child views
- check if the child is visible/opaque
- build up a list of each child's position/size
- use that list to do your own background clipping

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. How would you clip inside a path?